# Wordpress page editor can't switch between text and visual mode when Slider Revolution plugin is active

Tags: wordpress, slider

In Wordpress, if I disable the Slider Revolution plugin, the page editor works fine. Otherwise, I can't switch between text and visual mode. This occurred after the latest theme update (Avada theme) which includes the Slider Revolution plugin.

If the last website backup is restored, everything works fine. But then the theme and plugins are outdated.

I've tried different browsers, clearing browser cache, and reinstalling the Wordpress core program.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: you should contact with theme support

Comment: I would also check plugin support and make sure you are using the latest version of slider plugin. Themes often bundle old versions.